# Jar on Raspberry Pi not responding after a long time

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, daemon, raspbian

Hello I made a java program with friend that is designed to run 24/7 as a personal assistant on a headless Raspberry Pi. It basically can be used as an alarm and to tell us the weather or news etc. So in order to have it run 24/7 headless, I followed directions from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/executing-a-jar-file-when-raspberry-boots-up) to have the `jar` start when the Pi boots up (so it runs as a daemon).

Everything is fine for the first couple hours to a day, but then after an extended period of time (so about a day or more) the `jar` becomes unresponsive, yet when I SSH into the Pi then it seems like the Pi almost "wakes up" and everything works again.

I read that the Raspberry Pi does not have a sleep mode, so I am confused as to what the cause is, and how to turn it off so that the `jar` is truly responsive 24/7.

I was wondering if daemon threads go to sleep or if threads generally go to sleep if they do not do much, because right now our program mostly "sleeps" as it waits for events to occur (like a certain time to hit for the alarm to activate etc.), so it does not do much for most of the time.

Comment: "I wrote a program and it doesn't work but it can't be something in my code of course...so what is wrong?" is a question that's *very* unlikely to elicit an answer.  Probably the machine is broken or there's a bug in the JRE, or the OS kernel -- any one of those three, since we know for sure it isn't your application ;) ;)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that is fair to say, I was actually more wondering about the long-term behavior of daemons in unix or threads in general, I was not asking for a someone to debug my program, and I think that is a fair question..

Answer (score 0):

> I was actually more wondering about the long-term behavior of daemons in unix or threads in general

They run until they stop.  The system won't stop them arbitrarily, and you already know the pi can't go to sleep.  If by "unresponsive" you mean "slow" and the system has been doing other things, it could just be because the JRE was swapped out (but it does not sound like this is the issue).

You might want to look at the memory profile over time.  If it steadily increases, to the point where it is much bigger after a few days when the problem occurs, this is a clue something is wrong.  I think it is nearly impossible to truly "leak" memory with java, but it is certainly possible to accidentally build up masses of it that aren't really being used.  You may be interested in [this](http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/plog/).

Beyond that, you need to implement more fine grained logging in the program; apparently it counts time one way or another.  Have it wake up at short regular intervals regardless of whether there is anything to do and report its state.  This may mysteriously "fix" the problem, or it may provide a real clue. Robust logging is critical to monitoring persistent processes.  Everytime it does something -- anything -- log it.  Everytime a certain amount of time passes without it doing anything, log that.  **Too much logging is better than not enough.**